# iPhone app retina and nonretina

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5, iphone-5

I have developed both ipad and iPhone app in xcode 4.5 and did it by checking the device :

```
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
   //code for ipad.Adjusting sizes for all the controls 
}
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
   //code for iphone.Adjusting sizes for all the controls 
}
```

But when I check for Retina(4) for iphone5 in simulator all the sizes of controls are changed and the prevoius resolutions which I gave for iphone are not matched.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Use autolayout. This is the situation that it's meant for.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Do I need to do it for iPad also ?

Answer (score 1):

```
This is the other optional way to find out for check iPhone5

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

if you want to show the component from the bottom..

```
#define GET_Y_AXIS_FROM_BOTTOM(a)(( double )([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height)-a)
```

CGRectMake(0,GET_Y_AXIS_FROM_BOTTOM(50),320,50)

Comment: Means you are asking for reset the size for iphone5?

Comment: What Im asking is if I have used a tabbar to start from (0,411,320,50) in iphone .Should I change this size again if it is iphone5?Because when I test keeping the same I could see tabbar in middle of screen ?How can it resize automatically if it is any of the iphone device ?

Comment: yes, you have to bcoz iphone 5 screen is 568 px long,and iphone 4 screen is 480 px long.

Comment: But it appears from the top now.What should I do?

Comment: I have updated the answer again plz check just replace 411 with 50

Answer (score 0):

You have to either create two xib file (one for iPhone4 and iPhone5),or have to create all control programmatically,and put it in loop, like this.

```
 CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        //put your iphone 5 control here
    } else {
        //put your iphone 4 control here
    }
```

Comment: See if next release of iphone comes then again we have to write for that?Is there anything to check and make it automatically adjust all the controls based on the releases of iphone.

Comment: no, at this time you have to change your interface according to divice.and who knows that in next releases apple will give us some functionality to auto adjust.(apple rock)

Answer (score 0):

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{

    //code

}
else
{

    //code

}
```